# Fill Gaps with Comma in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a long list set up like this..

```
"12707081"  7376007 "1234"  "TEST"   "TEST NAME"    ""  "2012-04-03"    ""      ""  "TEST@TEST.COM"     "X" "Y" "X"
```

In between each set of "" there is a different length of blank spaces. How would I replace only the space between each set of "" to be a comma. What I want would be something like this..

```
"X"                       "Y"
```

replace result:

```
"X","Y"
```

Keep in mind though that the amount of spaces in between varies throughout the document.

I essentially want to fil the gaps in between each set to be a comma

Comment: What is the expected result for your example? Especially `"12707081"  7376007 "1234"` must be modify into what?

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu click find and replace. Replace every double space with a single space by replace all multiple times till you get no match found. Then replace " " with ","

Comment: You are only replacing double space to a single space.. Single space is not replaced

Comment: You're right, sorry. But what to do with `"12707081"  7376007 "1234"?`

Comment: What's should it be? I mean how do you expect it to be as a result

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked OP before answering.